# Force a generic type to be an interface?

Tags: java, generics

It looks like this is impossible to do, but does anyone have a clever way around this problem?

```
public class SomeClassIterableWrapper<S, T extends SomeClass & S> implements Iterable<S>
```

Where `S` is supposed to be an interface of some unknown type and `SomeClass` is a 2D array with a row index, similar in functionality to a bidirectional JDBC resultset.  Subclasses of `SomeClass` have custom getters and setters for each column.  I want to be able to iterate through this structure like I would a List.  I want to implement a common interface between my `SomeClass` and Bean to have access to the getters and setters.  As such S needs to be that interface.  However the declaration I provided does not work.  Is there a way to work around this?

edit to show my desired implementation:

```
public class SomeClassIterableWrapper<S, T extends SomeClass & S> implements Iterable<S>{

T object;

public SomeClassWrapper(T object){
    this.object = object;
}

@Override
public Iterator<S> iterator() {
    object.setIndex(-1);
    return new SomeClassIterator<S>();
}

private class SomeClassIterator<S> implements Iterator<S> {

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return object.index() < object.rowSize() - 1;
    }

    @Override
    public S next() {
        object.next();
        //safe because only interface methods allowed, can't further manipulate index
        return object; 
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {
        object.deleteRow();
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by <T extends SomeClass & S>? Java does not support multiple inheritance. Do you want a guarantee that T extends SomeClass AND implements S?

Comment: Like it says in the description, S is an interface

Comment: @LudwigMagnusson, you can only use `extends X` within a generic type parameter definition, regardless of whether `X` is a class or an interface.

Comment: If `S` should be a common interface for `SomeClass` and Bean then why not do `SomeClass implements S`and define `SomeClassIterableWrapper<S, T extends SomeClass>`?

Comment: I find this question a bit confusing. Could you add some more code showing how you intend to use S, T and SomeClass?

Comment: @Ludwig Magnusson, class SomeClass<T extends MyIfs<T> & Comparable<T> & Serializable> is valid notation it does not imply multiple inheritance.

Comment: ... and DOES imply that Comparable and Serializable are interfaces. That's what OP is aiming at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you parameterize `SomeClass` with `S`? Then you could have

```
public class SomeClassIterableWrapper<S, T extends SomeClass<S>> 
      implements Iterable<S>{
```

Comment: I'm considering parametizing SomeClass as an entirely different solution.  One in which SomeClass would implement Iterable itself.  However I don't want to use this solution as SomeClass is used a lot in the existing code base.

Comment: You might also consider using composition instead of inheritance, so your existing subclasses could instead hold a reference to `SomeClass`, and be parameterized.

Answer (score 0):

I think the S in extends SomeClass & S

public class SomeClassIterableWrapper

has to be a definite class because in this context,
S has to be a class that is extending something.

Is there a way you can narrow down what the
potential classes that are used in place of S are?
You could use multiple ampersands if you have multiple
classes that T should extend

Comment: Yes, that correctly identifies the problem.  Unfortunately the number of interfaces S would describe is not something that can be narrowed down, and in fact will only grow over time.

Answer (score -1):

I confess that I don't fully comprehend the problem but this is what I suggest:
Create an interface of `S`. It contains one method ad it returns the `S` object.

```
public interface SWrapper<S> {

  S getS();

}
```

Then create an implementation:

```
public class SImpl implements SWrapper<SImpl> {

    @Override
    public SImpl getS() {
        return this;
    }

}
```

You can now create:

```
public class SomeClass<T extends SomeClass & SWrapper<T>> {

    private final T object;

    public SomeClass(T object) {
        this.object = object;
    }
}
```

You will have to modify your usage a bit but perhaps it works.